# Is trigger in Oacle the part of request?

Tags: sql, hibernate, oracle11g, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I use **Spring Repository**, And **Oracle DB**.
I have a table and trigger that fire on insert/update/delete. If I execute some insert/delete/update against the table and trigger got an SQL error (locked resources or something else) will the Repository method got an exception? Or Oracle trigger executes as separated part of insert/delete/update statements?

Comment: I cannot speak specifically for Spring, but it *should*.  If the trigger generates an error, then the transaction fails and the calling code should be made aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Spring Repository, but I do know that in - for example: Oracle Forms, Application Express, Reports - trigger error propagates all the way up. **Everything** stops in that case.

Suppose that I have a form and enter some data. Database trigger fires and tries to do *whatever* it does, and it fails with `raise_application_error`. Nothing gets completed, and I see an error in my form, e.g. "ORA-20001: my custom error".

Therefore, I presume that you'd experience the same in Spring Repository. After all, wouldn't cost much to test it, right? I would if I could, but I can't so - do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Your Spring Repository will be error out when you trying to insert data into table. Our DML command will not performed  if there is any error in our associated trigger.

Mostly i use DML in my PLSQL procedure for insert and use GET_LOCKED_TRANSACTION() procedure to check if any resource is busy.

FUNCTION GET_LOCKED_TRANSACTION
  (
    P_WIP_ENTITY_ID          IN NUMBER,
    P_PRODUCTION_NOTE_NUMBER IN NUMBER
  ) RETURN BOOLEAN IS
    ROW_LOCKED EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ROW_LOCKED, -54);
  BEGIN
    /*  cURSOR WITH nOWAIT Attribute */
    FOR CC IN (SELECT *
                 FROM myTable
                WHERE WIP_ENTITY_ID = P_WIP_ENTITY_ID
                  FOR UPDATE NOWAIT) LOOP
      NULL;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN FALSE;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN ROW_LOCKED THEN
      RETURN TRUE;
  END GET_LOCKED_TRANSACTION;